# The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9843740

Tags: wcf

I am getting the following error in WCF how can I repro on my test environment and what is the fix for the problem ? How could I set timeout in milliseconds to reproduce in test environment .

```
The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9843740. 
Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or 
increase the Send Timeout value on the Binding. 
The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is unrelated to the SendTimeOut property, I don’t think the following code segments could solve the problem.

```
closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
```

It more relates to your actual scenery.
For example, the client used multiple Stream objects and did not close the channel appropriately. there is something wrong with the Nettcpbinding configuration,authentication, ReadQuotas, and so on.
I would like you could post your complete configuration, try to reproduce your issue.
Besides, try to apply the below service behavior in you binding property.

```
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="20" maxConcurrentSessions="20" maxConcurrentInstances="30" />
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.